# Backbone.js render data from response

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js

Ok, first of all, I'm newbie in `Backbone.js` usage, I'm playing with it with help of documentation and examples that I found online. I've managed to configure it on above `node.js` and issue that bothers me for now I think is purely lack of my `Backbone` knowledge, and solution is I hope pretty simple.
I've divided `Backbone` in several documents and got all working together with help of `Require.js`:

```
RecipeSearch.js
router.js
models(folder) ¬
               recipe_collection_m.js
               recipe_m.js
views(folder) ¬
               search_v.js
templates(folder) ¬
                   search_t.html
```

RecipeSearch.js simply fires everything:

```
define(["router"],function(router) {
    var initialize = function(hash) {
        if(!hash){
            window.location.hash = 'search';
        }else{
            window.location.hash = hash;
        }
        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

router.js is where I handle the routes:

```
define(["views/search_v","models/recipe_collection_m"]
    ,function(searchView, recipeCollection){

    var RecipeSearchSpace = Backbone.Router.extend({
        currentView: null,

        routes: {
            "search":              "search",    // #search
            "search/:query":        "search"  // #search/kiwis
        },

        changeView: function(view) {
            this.currentView = view;
            this.currentView.render();
        },

        search: function(query) {
            if(query){
                var RecipeCollection = new recipeCollection();
                RecipeCollection.url = '/search/'+query;

                RecipeCollection.fetch({
                    success: function(response,xhr) {
                        console.log("Inside success:");
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function (errorResponse) {
                        console.log("Inside error:");
                        console.log(errorResponse);
                    }
                 });
                this.changeView(new searchView({
                    collection: RecipeCollection
                }));

            }
            else{
                this.changeView(new searchView());
            }

        }


    });


    return new RecipeSearchSpace();

});
```

in models folder are located model and collection,

recipe_collection_m.js:

```
define(['models/recipe_m'], function(Search) {
    var searchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({


        model: Search


    });

    return searchCollection;
});
```

recipe_m.js:

```
define(function(require) {
    var Search = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults:{
            recipe:"no results"
        }

    });
    return Search;
});
```

and finally view called recipe_v.js:

```
define(['text!templates/search_t.html','models/recipe_collection_m'],
    function(SearchTemplate, RecipeCollection){
    var searchView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el:$(".content"),

        events:{
            'click button#search':'send_query'
        },

        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render','send_query');

            this.collection = new RecipeCollection();


            this.render();

        },

        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(SearchTemplate);
            $('.search_form').append("<button id='search'>Find</button>");
            $(this.el).append("<ul class='recipes_list'></ul>");
        },

        send_query:function(){
            $(".search_form").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            var value = $(".wanted").val();
            window.location.hash = '#search/'+ value;
        }


    });

    return searchView;
});
```

and finally search_t.html, the template:

```
<p class="text">test search</p>

<form class="search_form">
    <input class="wanted" type="text"/>
</form>
```

My problem is that I do not know how to render properly the response I got from server to that search_v.js(SearchTemplate). The case is next:

When I hit the root of my test server

- application redirects me to /#search tag successfully,

  - there the SearchTemplate renders successully along with genereted `button Find` and list `<ul>` called `recipes_list` as you can seee in the view.
  - I insert value (lets say I typed in "**example**") in `.wanted` input and click the button `#search`, the `send_query` function fires successfully
  - url in browser changes to the localhost:3000/#search/`example` successfully
  - I fire `Developer tools` in `Chrome` check the `Network` tab and there is server response called `Example` received successfully
  - and when I check the `Console`  I got: 
                                          **Inside success:
                                          s {length: 6, models: Array[6], _byId: Object, url: "/search/`example`", constructor: function…}**
  - which I guess it means that it fetched correctly to `RecipeCollection`

And here is my dead and, Now I wanna render this to `SearchView`, I tried to send collection to it by:

```
this.changeView(new searchView({
                collection: RecipeCollection
            }));
```

And I'm not quite sure that I got this collection there, and if it sends like this to view, how to call in there and for example render it to that `<ul>`?

Comment: First you: `this.changeView(new searchView({ collection: RecipeCollection }));` in the router. Then in your `SearchView` your creating a new collection in the initialize method, so it may be overriding the collection you are passing to it. Also in your `SearchView` you need to `return this` in the render method in order to use the render method in the router

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    search: function (query) {
    var self = this;
    if (query) {
        var RecipeCollection = new recipeCollection();
        RecipeCollection.url = '/search/' + query;
        RecipeCollection.fetch({
            success: function (response, xhr) {
                console.log("Inside success:");
                console.log(response);
                self.changeView(new searchView({
                    collection: response
                }))
            },
            error: function (errorResponse) {
                console.log("Inside error:");
                console.log(errorResponse);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        this.changeView(new searchView());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how to render it then on view? or just check if it is there somehow?

Comment: If you don't include it in the `success` callback, your collection won't be initialized. Because the data fetching is made asynchronously.